# django method is there, but evaluatesto NoneType when I try to call it

Tags: python, django, methods, django-models

I have a custom method inside one of the Django models, it does some routine DB data fetching and summing. Here is it:

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc, now 
...


class Project(models.Model):
...
    def getTotalMonthlyBackers(self, monthdate=now()):
        from pledger.models import DonationHistory 

        return (DonationHistory.objects
                                 .filter(project=self)
                                 .filter(datetime_sent__gte=datetime(monthdate.year, monthdate.month, 1))
                                 .aggregate(Count('user', distinct=True))['user__count'])
```

when I try to call the method through

```
print project.getTotalMonthlyBackers()
```

I'm getting error: `'NoneType' object is not callable`

However if I output the method itself just to check if it's not a typo:

```
print project.getTotalMonthlyBackers
```

I get: `<bound method Project.getTotalMonthlyBackers of <Project: Putty>>`

So the method is there and bound to the certain `Project` object. 
There is something very obvious in Python I can't get about calling this method, but I couldn't figure it out from the manuals.

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/mnt/hgfs/Projects/BitFund/Sources/source/project/views/project_view_details.py" in view
  101.     print project.getTotalMonthlyBackers()
File "/mnt/hgfs/Projects/BitFund/Sources/source/project/models.py" in getTotalMonthlyBackers
  76.                                  .filter(datetime_sent__gte=datetime(monthdate.year, monthdate.month, 1))

Exception Type: TypeError at /putty_1
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback for the `not callable` error? (More precisely, are you sure that's the line, and not something within the function, that is raising the exception?)

Comment: @recursive added import statement

Comment: Other than `now`, I see `filter`, `datetime`, `aggregate`, and `Count`.  I would start with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't imported the `datetime` constructor yet, also if you use it you will get a **naive** datetime, which will produce a warming because that structure doesn't contain a `tzinfo` object, so try using a Time Zone aware constructor for that **datetime** or use the `make_aware`.

Check out this piece of documentation about the topic, and I'm sure you will solve it in the most proper way [Timezones and utils](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)

Comment: Hmm, I'm using `now()` from `django.utils.timezone` and assuming that it will be TZ aware, according to exactly that manpage. I'm wrong?

Comment: Basically here `.filter(datetime_sent__gte=datetime(monthdate.year, monthdate.month, 1))` where you create a naive datetime out of a TZ aware object. I'm not sure if you could do `.filter(datetime_sent__gte=datetime(monthdate.year, monthdate.month, 1, monthdate.tzinfo))`.

Comment: yep, almost. If somebody will look here, you should use this to get tz-aware date:
    `datetime_sent__gte=datetime.datetime(monthdate.year, monthdate.month, 1, tzinfo=monthdate.tzinfo)`
i.e. pass it as `tzinfo` param.

Answer (score 1):

As the traceback shows, it's not the method that is being treated as `None`, but one of the functions that you call within it. I would guess that you have redefined either `datetime` or `Count` somewhere else in that module.

Also, this isn't the problem, but note that you shouldn't call `now()` in the function definition: doing so fixes the default as of the time the process started, rather than getting a new value each time it is called. You should do this instead:

```
def getTotalMonthlyBackers(self, monthdate=None):
    if monthdate is None:
        monthdate = now()
```

Comment: yep, it was all of them actually. I didn't figure it out yet why, but I had to reimport all required utilities on the method level, while I have already imported it on the module level.
Monthdate - yep, I'll use it, thanks.